# Display Multiple Tables In A Single View In ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on building a website in ASP.NET Core MVC (the latest version). I have Animals table and Categories table,looking like this:

[image]

On my AdminController I have Index action that should show eventually a table that displays the animal's data table (name, age, picture, description) and ALSO its category. It meant that I need the data from both Animals and Categories tables.

The problom is that I don't understand how to do this combination. I've tried to use ViewModel but I still don't now how to approach both animal's data and it's category for each animal?

Right now everything works fine except the Category name part - which stays empty.
I think my problom is on the foreach part but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code-
Admin Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    readonly IAnimalService _animalService;
    readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public AdminController(IAnimalService animalService, ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _animalService = animalService;
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var model = new AdminViewModel()
        {
            Animals = await _animalService.GetAllAsync(),
            Categories = await _categoryService.GetAnimalCategory()

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Admin ViewModel:

```
namespace PetShop.Client.Models
{
    public class AdminViewModel
    {
        public IQueryable<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
@model PetShop.Client.Models.AdminViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> Model.Animals.FirstOrDefault().Name);
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> Model.Animals.FirstOrDefault().BirthDate);
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> Model.Animals.FirstOrDefault().Description);
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> Model.Animals.FirstOrDefault().PhotoUrl);
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> Model.Categories.FirstOrDefault().Name);
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Animals) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include category in `_animalService.GetAllAsync()`

```
return await _context.Animals.Include(i => i.Category);
```

And IMHO I can't see what do you need `IQueryable<Category> Categories` for. And maybe you will have to change `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` too.

Comment: I added this to my repository and animalService, and also fix it to IEnumerable and it's working. Thank you very much!